# Detect keypress without drawing canvas or frame on tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to detect when a button is being pressed anytime when my python3.4 program is running. How do I do it without taking text input?

Comment: Edited to be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a OS-level hotkey. How that's done will depend on your OS.

Comment: No, I'll need to use in in Tkinter itself, because I'm running a `root= Tk()` and then a `root.mainloop()` in my code, and there is nothing else

Comment: Could you provide a small example? I use Windows 10

Comment: Tkinter alone has no way to monitor keystrokes if it's not in focus. You will have to use something else. For your application, a OS hotkey would be best.

Comment: There's tons of examples out there; [this was one of the first google hits](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/catch_system_wide_hotkeys.html) and seems to be a good example. Someone has even [written a module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/system_hotkey/1.0.3) to make it extra easy.