# Monitor keypress in tkinter without focus

Tags: python, tkinter, focus, bind

I am writing a small timing module in Python using tkinter. In that regard, I would like to globally monitor when the escape key is pressed for stopping the timing.

Unfortunately, tkinters ".bind" and ".bind_all" functions only pick up keystrokes when the window is in focus.

I have looked at several other solutions for logging keystrokes including the packages "keyboard" and "pynput", however these packages requires running a while loop which makes the tkinter GUI freeze up and stop working.

I found this thread, but it is not very helpful for specifically showing how it can be done: [Detect keypress without drawing canvas or frame on tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45017956/detect-keypress-without-drawing-canvas-or-frame-on-tkinter)

Some different options i tried

Option 1: Using the tkinter loop function, but doesn't register when key is pressed

```py
import keyboard
def _check_esc_pressed(self):
    if self.run_active and keyboard.press('esc'):
        self.Lap()
        self.Stop()
    self.after(50, self._check_esc_pressed())
```

Option 2: Freezes the tkinter client

```py
import keyboard  
def _check_esc_pressed(self):
    while True:  
        if keyboard.is_pressed('esc'): 
            self.Lap()
            self.Stop()
            break  
        else:
            pass
```

Option 3: Freezes the tkinter client

```py
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
def on_release(self, key):
    if key == Key.esc:
        self.Lap()
        self.Stop()
        # Stop listener
        return False

def _check_esc_pressed(self):
    def on_press(key):
        pass
    with Listener(
            on_press=on_press,
            on_release=on_release) as listener:
        listener.join()
```

I expect that pressing escape will terminate the "_check_esc_pressed" function, register a lap and stop the timer. The check for escape should only be processed while a run is active

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to the issue by using the [system_hotkey](https://pypi.org/project/system_hotkey/) package for python. This package allows you to assign system-wide hotkeys that work without focus on the tkinter program.

```py
from system_hotkey import SystemHotkey
hk = SystemHotkey()
hk.register(['alt', 'q'], callback=lambda event: self.Start())
hk.register(['alt', 'w'], callback=lambda event: self.Stop())
```

Bear in mind that any hotkey added like this will make the registered hotkey  combination inaccessible to other programs.

Answer (score 3):

In case you still need an answer, or others find this useful...

The answer may lie in the code we can't see - By putting the app's logic in another thread, it allows tkinter to do its thing without freezing.

The code below follows your (slightly modified) option 2:

```
import queue
import keyboard  
import threading
import time
import tkinter as tk

def app_main_loop(my_label):
    # Create another thread that monitors the keyboard
    input_queue = queue.Queue()
    kb_input_thread = threading.Thread(target=_check_esc_pressed, args=(input_queue,))
    kb_input_thread.daemon = True
    kb_input_thread.start()
    
    # Main logic loop
    run_active = True
    while True:
        if not input_queue.empty():
            if (run_active) and (input_queue.get() == "esc"):
                run_active = False
                Lap(my_label)
                Stop()
        time.sleep(0.1)  # seconds

def _check_esc_pressed(input_queue):
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('esc'):
            input_queue.put("esc")
        time.sleep(0.1) # seconds

def Lap(my_label):
    my_label.configure(text = "Lap")

def Stop():
    print("Stopped")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Create the ui
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
    my_label = tk.Label(root, text="Hello World!")
    my_label.pack()
    
    # Run the app's main logic loop in a different thread
    main_loop_thread = threading.Thread(target=app_main_loop, args=(my_label, ))
    main_loop_thread.daemon = True
    main_loop_thread.start()
    
    # Run the UI's main loop
    root.mainloop()
```