# how do i display a grid of images (and have them them transparent until a keyboard key is pressed)

Tags: javascript, python, html, c++

any language.

im wanting to make a program that will show what ability's im using in a game and have the picture of the ability's in a grid like ortholinear keyboard keys. it would be cool if the abilitys where tansparent untill the key is pressed then go opaque until i let go.

iv been trying to find out how to do it with python but im not having much luck. i started with tkinter and i dont realy think that has the tools i need then i tryed matplotlib that seams tobe morefor data stuff

if somone could point me in the right direction id appreciate it

Comment: This will probably be easiest using HTML/JS/CSS. `<img` tag can display and image `style=opacity:0` or `style:opacity:1` can change transparency, `HTMLElement.addEventListener('keydown', someFunction)` can run javascript which can then modify the styles of the images. `flex` css can be used to display your images in a grid. Hope that gives you enough to get started!

Comment: There are some condition that you need to take in mind too, because Python can be used for macro, will the game ban you if the game detect python is on?
If that is the case, I suggest @Modularizer answer

Comment: @Joshua you are right I didn't really take into account the actual interface with the game. What I described above (using the keylistener) will only work if you are focused on (have clicked on) the page of the browser with the images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you give this link a read: [Monitor keypress in tkinter without focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57285092/monitor-keypress-in-tkinter-without-focus)

You can refer to the answer that is not accepted, it shows how to accept key even if the program is not focus on.

My suggestion is that, you create a "ability layout" in tkinter, then you assign the key of the ability layout to the actual keyboard. The background or layout opacity is constantly low, and once it is pressed, you trigger the opacity to be high.

The problem you may face is that, **you might get ban if you tried to run it, as we are unsure about the game ban mechanics.**

Comment: The thing is it would only be read inputs of the pc, and it would no be interactive with the game at all. Like if you're using push to talk in discord

Comment: @sneekcreeper, edited my answer, and do you mind elaborate your "it would no be interactive with the game at all"? Please edit your question and add it on.

Comment: @sneekcreeper, another add on, as what you want is that, "show what ability's im using in a game and have the picture of the ability's in a grid like ortholinear keyboard keys."
So what you want, is actually just a line of ability that will light up, for example, you press Ctrl + E for you first skill, so you press Ctrl + E in game, and your "layout" will light up your first skill.

Comment: i would have a picture of all the abilities in a folded saved on my PC and the program could get the pictures from there. that way all it needs to do is see what keys I'm pressing and that's it. it wouldn't need to grab any data from the game.

 a line could work but the thing is there's a lot of ability (it's an MMO)

Comment: Yeah, so my direction should work? What is troubling you?

Comment: yeah, i think it will work. i was just trying to say I don't thing ill have a problem of getting banned

Comment: If so, please set my answer as the correct answer.