# Tkinter Control- and Double- numbers above 5 keybindings work, but not a whole lot else

Tags: python, tkinter

## Original Post

I'm trying to implement keyboard shortcuts in Tkinter with something other than Control- (as in Control-x), but have discovered that not a whole lot works on my machine. In the sample code below, only the Control and Double-6 functions ever fire.

Am I missing something? I'm on OSX Ventura using python 3.8.13, and I get the same behavior whether I use my laptop keyboard or an offboard keyboard.

### Original Example

(with in-line fixes for all but Alt)

```
from tkinter import *

class GUI:
    def __init__(self,root):    
        ex = Label(root, text="Example just here for whatever.")
        ex.pack()
        ex.focus()
        root.bind("<Alt-x>", self.option_func)
        root.bind("<Control-x>", self.control_func) # works fine
        root.bind("<Shift-x>", self.shift_func) # fix: Shift-X
        root.bind("<Double-3>", self.doublethree_func) # fix: double mousewheel click
        root.bind("<Double-6>", self.doublesix_func) # fix: press 6-key twice

    def option_func(self,event=None):
        print ("WORKING: Alt-x")
    def control_func(self,event=None):
        print ("WORKING: Control-x")
    def shift_func(self,event=None):
        print ("WORKING: Shift-x")
    def doublethree_func(self,event=None):
        print ("WORKING: Double-3")
    def doublesix_func(self,event=None):
        print ("WORKING: Double-6")

root = Tk()
app = GUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

## Updates

1. Changing the `Shift-x` to `Shift-X` fixes the Shift key activation.
2. `Double-6` is activated when I press the 6 numerical key twice. `Double-3` is apparently activated by double-clicking the mousewheel.
3. Simple bindings, like `root.bind("<s>", self.s_func)` work fine.
4. This leaves just the Alt/Option key.

### Alt Keybinding Deep Dive Example

```
from tkinter import *

class GUI:
    def __init__(self,root):    
        ex = Label(root, text="Example just here for whatever.")
        ex.pack()
        ex.focus()
        #root.bind("<Option>", self.option_func) # _tkinter.TclError: bad event type or keysym "Option"
        #root.bind("<Alt>", self.alt_func) # _tkinter.TclError: bad event type or keysym "Alt"
        root.bind("<Alt-x>", self.altmod_func) # doesn't trigger on macOS
        root.bind("<Alt_L>", self.altl_func) # triggers on macOS
        # root.bind("<Alt_L-x>", self.altlmod_func) # _tkinter.TclError: extra characters after detail in binding

    def option_func(self,event=None):
        print ("WORKING: Option")
    def alt_func(self,event=None):
        print ("WORKING: Alt")
    def altl_func(self,event=None):
        print ("WORKING: Alt_L")
    def altmod_func(self,event=None):
        print ("WORKING: Alt-x")
    def altlmod_func(self,event=None):
        print ("WORKING: Alt_L-x")

root = Tk()
app = GUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Do simple, unmodified key bindings work as expected? Does it make a difference if you include the `KeyPress` or `Key` event type in the event sequence? https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/event-sequences.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57285092/monitor-keypress-in-tkinter-without-focus

Comment: @PM2Ring I've put up some updates from other commenters that explains/fixes all but the Alt/Option keyboard binding. And I have been able to get something like `root.bind("<s>", self.s_func)` to trigger correctly.

Comment: On OSX you can use the modifiers `Option-` and `Command-`, though there are some keys that are owned by the OS that you can't rebind. See the section [Modifiers](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/bind.htm#M6) on the bind man page of the tcl/tk documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get *almost* all of these to work in **Windows 10**, with some caveats:

1. `Shift-x` should be changed to `Shift-X` (capital X) to account for the <kbd>shift</kbd> key being held since `x` is treated as a different keysym from `X`
2. <s>I don't have a 6th mouse button, so I can't test `Double-6`, but `Double-3` is working as expected. Are you sure your mouse supports this?</s>
   ***SEE BELOW***
3. AFAIK, OS X treats mouse button 3 as "Middle Click", so if what you want is "double right-click" you should use `Double-2` instead.

- You may also need to change `Alt-x` to `Alt_L-x` on Mac OS, but I can't test this at the moment! (I've a MacBook at home I can try this on later)

---

***ADDENDUM:***

According to the [tcl documentation](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/bind.htm), a maximum of 5 mouse buttons are supported, and cursory reading seems to indicate that (depending on your platform) buttons 4 and 5 are the mousewheel.

Comment: The Shift-X comment fixed that one, nice catch!

Comment: As for the 'Double'...when I press the 6-key twice (as in, the number key), the function activates...no mouse required! But you're correct on the Double-3, that apparently is activated by a double mousewheel click.

Comment: The Alt_L-x is throwing a `_tkinter.TclError: extra characters after detail in binding`. I'll dig into it a bit more...

Comment: I wonder if `Option-x` would work on a Mac in lieu of `Alt`...apologies, it's been a minute since I've done any tkinter on my Mac. And I couldn't get `Double-6` to do anything on Windows, but I'm also on a TKL keyboard so it may be that I'm using the "wrong" number 6 key.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried `Option-x` and it also doesn't work. No need to apologize, these are easy for me to try out on my setup!

Comment: Ah darn, it was worth a shot! I vaguely remember having to figure out `Alt` key binding on OS X once, but I can't remember where I ended up.

Comment: The plot thickens: `root.bind('<Key>', lambda e: print(e.__dict__))` should print me the complete attribute `__dict__` of any `Key` event, but nothing happens for `Alt` at all...

Comment: I've updated my main question with a deep dive into Alt. `<Alt_L>` works. `<Alt_L-x` throws an error (as does unmodified `<Option>` and `<Alt>`)

Comment: I think I might just use `<Control` plus number keys at this point. I need this to work on a few others' machines, so something reliable would be best.